# Не найден класс GsonBuilder. В чём причина?

Tags: java, исключения, gson, library, зависимости

В IDEA через **Структура проекта**>**Модули**>**Зависимости** добавил библиотеку *com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6*. При создании объекта (`new GsonBuilder()`) получаю `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder`. В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего, при сборке проекта не происходит добавление библиотеки в сборку. Если вы используете maven или gradle, просто напрямую добавьте эту библиотеку в конфигурацию сборки в виде зависимости проекта. Если не используете, то советую использовать, так как без них для сборки проекта нужно грамотно указать зависимости которые должны быть добавлены. Делается это если не ошибаюсь через ключевое слово -classpath. И выглядит это примерно так

```
javac -classpath .\mylib.jar .\Main.java
```

И тот же ключ надо добавить при исполнении (если я ничего не путаю).